# Attempting to Highlight Cells Based on String within Cell

Tags: string, excel, vba

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following:

First, determine if I'm in the correct row of cells based on the String value of the cell.
i.e If the current cell's string value contains the string AB1 or AB2, go through the entire row.

Once that has been determined, I would like to highlight the cells either green (if the cell holds a value greater than 5) or blue (if the cell holds a value between 4 and 5).

The above if block is not giving me trouble, it's the initial procedure.

What is stopping me from completing this is the run-time [error '91']: "Object variable or With block variable not set".

I have some programming experience, but no VBA experience. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ChangeCellColor()

Dim columnD As Range
Dim str1, str2 As String
Dim currCell As Range
Dim rightCell As Range
Dim i As Long

str1 = "AB1"
str2 = "AB2"

Columns(1).Font.Color = vbBlack

For i = 1 To Rows.Count

'If the current cell in the D column contains either the string AB1 or AB2, it will look into the values here.
If (currCell.Cells(i, 4).Value = str1) Or (currCell.Cells(i, 4).Value = str2) Then
    'From the cell range of
    For j = 1 To Range("E10").End(xlToRight)
            If rightCell.Cells(j, 5) >= 5# Then
                rightCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            ElseIf (rightCell.Cells(j, 5) >= 4 And rightCell.Cells(j, 5) <= 4.99) Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
    Next j

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: the following code looks at each cell in Column D, and checks the cell value to determine if `cell.value = str1` or `str2`.  Then, it loops through each cell in that row, beginning with column E, changing the color based on your parameters.

Also, try the `Usedrange` property of the `Worksheet` object to get the number of rows you need.

```
Sub ChangeCellColor()

Dim str1, str2 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim col As Integer

str1 = "AB1"
str2 = "AB2"

Columns(1).Font.Color = vbBlack

For i = 1 To ThisWorksheet.Usedrange.Rows.Count

With ThisWorksheet
'If the current cell in the D column contains either the string AB1 or AB2, it will look into the     values here.
If .Cells(i, 4).Value = str1 Or .Cells(i, 4).Value = str2 Then
    col = .Range("D" & i).End(xltoRight).Column
    For j = 5 To col
            If .Cells(i, j).Value >= 5 Then
                .Cells(i,j).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else 
                If .Cells(i, j).Value >= 4 And .Cells(i, j).Value <= 4.99 Then
                .Cells(i,j).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            End If
    Next j
End If
End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! 

The first for loop is receiving a "object required" error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @rmdlp try replacing what I wrote (`ThisWorksheet`) with the worksheet name you are using.  You might try something like `Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`, or whatever sheet you are using, so the full statement reads `For i = 1 To Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Usedrange.Rows.Count`.  If you have further q's feel free to comment again.

Comment: Ahh, sorry for noobiness. Thank you, it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

There are a several issues...First, the error is because assigning to a Range variable requires the `Set` keyword, like so:

```
Set columnD = Range("D:D")
```

Second, in your `For` loop, you're comparing an integer to a range. If you want to loop through to the right-most column, you can do this:

```
For j = 1 to Range("E10").End(xlToRight).Column
```

Third, it looks like you've intended to use `i` for rows and `j` for columns? If so, you've got your `j`s in the wrong place.

Assuming that `i`s are rows and `j`s are columns, I believe that as you're checking your cells for values, you should be referencing `Cells(i, j,)`, (making both column and row selection dynamic) rather than hardcoding the value of `5`.

Finally, you actually don't need those three range variables that you declared at the beginning at all. There's no need to position the cell inside an existing range (though you can if you wish). VBA assumes that you're dealing with the active sheet of the active workbook. As long as those two assumptions hold, then `Cells(i,j)` works just fine. If you want to add some specificity/protect from running on the wrong sheet, you can use `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,j)`.

PS--I assume that the '#' after the 5 is a typo?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm currently looking into all your stated points and will get back to you!

Comment: `5#` indicates it is an integer. I've never seen it used in that sort of context, but if you try `Dim i as integer   i = 5.0` it will convert to `5#`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to either assign range value to currCell and rightCell or get rid of it.

```
Sub ChangeCellColor()

    Dim columnD As Range
    Dim str1, str2 As String
    Dim currCell As Range
    Dim rightCell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    str1 = "AB1"
    str2 = "AB2"

    Columns(1).Font.Color = vbBlack

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count

        'If the current cell in the D column contains either the string AB1 or AB2, it will look into the values here.
        If (Cells(i, 4).Value = str1) Or (Cells(i, 4).Value = str2) Then
            'From the cell range of
            For j = 1 To Range("E10").End(xlToRight)
                    If Cells(j, 5) >= 5 Then
                        Cells(j, 5).Interior.Color = vbRed
                    ElseIf (Cells(j, 5) >= 4 And Cells(j, 5) <= 4.99) Then
                        Cells(j, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    End If
            Next j

        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think possible without VBA but with Conditional Formatting and, for green, a formula rule such as:

```
=AND(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("AB1",$D1))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND("AB2",$D1)))),N(A1)>5)
```